# how to execute sql queries at run time from datastream's map or flatMap in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-batch

I am new to flink and want to understand how to run my use case with FLINK:
Application has three input data source
a) historical data
b) get all the live events from kafka
c) get the control event that will have a trigger condition

since the application is dealing with historical data so I thought that I will merge historical data and live data and will create a table on that stream.

To trigger the event we have to write the SQL query with help of control event that is the input source and that holds the where clause.

My problem is to build the SQL query as data is in Stream and when I do something like

```
DataStream<ControlEvent> controlEvent
controlEvent.map(new FlatMapFunction(String, String)
{
   @override
   public String flatMap(String s, Collector<String> coll)
   {
     tableEnv.execute("select * from tableName");   /// throw serialization exception
   }
});
```

it throws not serialization exception Localexecutionenvironment

Answer (score 0):

That sort of dynamic query injection is not (yet) supported by Flink SQL.

Update:

Given what you've said about your requirements -- that the variations in the queries will be limited -- what you might do instead is to implement this using the DataStream API, rather than SQL. This would probably be a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` that would hold some keyed state and you could broadcast in the updates to the query/queries.

Take a look at the [Fraud Detection Demo](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/01/15/demo-fraud-detection.html) as an example of how to build this sort of thing with Flink.

Comment: Thanks David for your quick reply. would you like to suggest any other approach to achieve this goal?

Comment: What are the queries like, and how much variation is required?

Comment: not expecting much variation, query will be something like 
SELECT * FROM EventMessages where referencData = ? and businessDate  < or > ? .. and some time there will be self join required.

1) simple sql query with 2-3 where clause field
2) self join type sql query

Comment: And volume of these controlSet will be approx 2-5K.

Comment: David, So you are suggesting to come out from sql approach as BroadCastProcessFunction will also not allow to execute the sql query due to same reason (Serialization issue ).. or I misunderstood your statement?

Comment: That's right: doing this with SQL is not possible, so I suggested an alternative. With SQL the query has to be fixed at compile time.